# Spark Accumulator value not read by task

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I am initializing an accumulator

`final Accumulator<Integer> accum = sc.accumulator(0);`

And then while in map function , I'm trying to increment the accumulator , then using the accumulator value in setting a variable.

```
JavaRDD<UserSetGet> UserProfileRDD1 = temp.map(new Function<String, UserSetGet>() {

            @Override
            public UserSetGet call(String arg0) throws Exception {

                    UserSetGet usg = new UserSetGet();

                    accum.add(1);
                    usg.setPid(accum.value().toString();


            }
  });
```

But Im getting the following error.

> 16/03/14 09:12:58 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in
>   stage 2.0 (TID 2) java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't read
>   accumulator value in task

EDITED - As per the answer from Avihoo Mamka, getting accumulator value in tasks is not possible.

So is there anyway I can achieve the same in parallel. Such that the Pid value gets set each time a variable(eg like static variable) is incremented in my map function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Spark docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#accumulators)

> Accumulators are variables that are only “added” to through an
>   associative operation and can therefore be efficiently supported in
>   parallel. They can be used to implement counters (as in MapReduce) or
>   sums
>
> ...
>
> **Only the driver** program can read the accumulator’s value, using its
>   `value` method.

Therefore, when trying to read the accumulator's value from within a task in Spark, means that you try to read its value from a worker, which is against the concept of reading the accumulator value only from the driver.

Comment: The whole idea is to increment a static variable , how do I achieve that ? ie in parallel

Comment: To increment a value is NOT reading its value. You definitely can do `accum += 1`, but not to read it from the task but only from the driver.

Comment: That's where you read the value: `usg.setPid(accum.value().toString();` which is not allowed within the task.

Comment: let me rephrase my question, I have to set the increment a variable , and then set it in my pojo varaible. And that should happens on all worker nodes in parallel. How do I achieve that in spark.

Comment: You can't use the accumulator's value to set your `POJO` value because your worker is not synced with all other workers as for the current state of the accumulator, only the driver is because of the parallelism and the manage of the executors, so you can't use the accumulator's value inside the worker.

Comment: Yes I understood I cant use accumulator in this situation, so is there anyway I can get this done in workers.

Comment: I guess static variable wont work here , am I right ?

Comment: Yes, a `static` variable won't help you across workers.. What is exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to set value on usg.setPid(..) based on the input size , ie how many times a call function is called from input.map(.... , the value of usg.setPid(..) should increment from 0 till the size of input. Hope I'm clear.

Comment: what is the solution for this scenario? I too need it for generating output.